# How to successfully back out to command prompt with Ctrl-Z in Neovim on Windows?

Tags: neovim, microsoft-windows

I know there's a number of ways you can suspend a Neovim/Vim session.

One way being <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> to jump back into the command prompt, and press `fg` and <kbd>ENTER</kbd> to go back into your Neovim/Vim session.

However....Doing this on Windows seems to freeze my console entirely to the point where I have to end the process by force. I don't want to use the `:!` command in neovim because that's not what I'm trying to do, and the `:sus` command essentially does the same thing as <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd>.

Is there a way to do this on Windows ? I know for sure that it can be done on Linux, and from a little research apparently <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> means end of input on DOS/Windows machines.

**EDIT: 3/12/18**
Also, as additional info I used both ConEmu and the default Windows command line

**EDIT: 3/14/18**
Using the `:shell` or `:sus` command seems to get it to work fine in regular vanilla Vim 8.0 in combination with `exit`, but that's only in regular Vim. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> also works as well if I edit my `_vimrc` to get rid of source `$VIMRUNTIME/mswin.vim` and `behave mswin`. I still will like this to be able to work in neovim

Comment: How do you use Neovim on Windows? Do you use it in cygwin (where `ctrl-z` should work), in the Windows Linux subsystem, in a Windows command line, etc?

Comment: @statox I tried it in ConEmu and in the default Windows command line

Comment: It's worth adding this info to your question. I don't really know how to help you with this issue, but knowing which terminal emulator you use will help other people to help you :)

Comment: FWIW, this works fine for me (using either `Ctrl-Z` or `:sus`) in regular Vim 7.4, running both under the Windows Command Prompt or in the bash provided by Git for Windows (on Windows 10). You might also like to try `:shell` which does something slightly different but similar.

Comment: It's always worked for me in Vim. One difference is that to exit the shell in Windows, you execute `exit` instead of `fg`.

Comment: @Rich I use "neovim" , that command doesn't work there. It throws an error saying `E492: Not an editor command: shell`. I just downloaded vanilla Vim 8.0. and `:shell` works fine there in combination with `exit` to return to your session.

Comment: `Ctrl-Z` works as well in regular Vim if I remove `source $VIMRUNTIME/mswin.vim` and `behave mswin` in my `_vimrc`, but I still will like to be able to get it to work in neovim

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found an answer, and apparently suspending the console doesn't work on Windows TUI as of yet.

https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/6660